# rails: devise ,cancan, rolify to get role name by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan, rolify

I can easily to test if a user has certain role by

```
if user.has_role? :admin
```

How do I get a user's role name?
Something like

```
users = User.all
user.each{ |user|
  puts user.role or users.role_name  ?
}
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me ,:username,:first_name,:last_name
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

role model

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :name,:id
  scopify
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use

```
user.roles.first.name
```

Comment: I got role name as  ["admin"] , how about just   admin

Comment: Are you always interested in the first role? Rather do you just have one role per user?

Comment: I would like to display role name for every user (different user has different role)